# How do I temporarily disable SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server (distributor and publisher) 2008 which is replicating using both snapshot and transactional replication to replicate to a couple of subscribers. There is plenty of information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/disable-publishing-and-distribution on how to permanently disable replication.

I don't want to permanently disable replication, just temporarily for a network outage that is scheduled for later this week.

I have learned my lesson that when things go amuck it's a complete disable, remove, and re-setup to get everything working again, and there are too many publications to make this an option just to temporarily disable this.

Comment: One option I have considered is to just disable all of the publication jobs that are created in SQL Agent but don't know of the ramifications that will have, and if everything will resynchronize when these are enabled again.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks SMW, that helps get me there, but with more research I found that in addition to this,  I will probably need to disable the SQL Agent jobs related to the snapshot publications and transactional publications or SQL Agent will try and run these jobs.  We will see Thursday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether there's going to be a network split between publisher and distributor or distributor and subscriber. Both of the below scenarios deal with transactional replication.

- publisher and distributor - the log reader agent will not be able to mark records as delivered to the distribution database and so will stay in the transaction log of the publisher longer than normal. This may cause log growth (depending on how much free space is in your log file currently).
- distributor and subscriber - assuming that the network outage is shorter than the minimum retention period for the distribution database, you should be able to just suspend the distribution jobs and everything should pick back up once the network is back online. Depending on the size of the backlog, it may be easier to re-initialize some (or all!) of your articles.

For snapshot replication, you shouldn't need to do much since the only time there's activity is when a snapshot is being created and delivered to the subscriber. You can just disable those jobs for the duration of your event and re-enable them when you're done.